# Soap ui start page: Cannot connect to internet

Tags: soap, soapui

[image]

I got this on my SOAP UI start page. My laptop is definitely connected to internet now. I am not using any proxy. So I don't know how I can get rid of this message. Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: can you try loading a WSDL and try if that is loading or not?, you can ignore the message and carry on with your work it will not affect actual working

Comment: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Starter-page-is-showing-that-computer-is-offline/td-p/28341 irs a false message and will not effect you

Comment: Took the laptop home, and this message is not displayed again. It shows connected. So this issue has something to do with my company's environment.

Comment: it can come at home as well.. just play around with soap ui and open the help and click on starter page , you might see the error again. but should not effect the functioning of the app